# SUBSTITUTE Error: "Longer than the limit of 50000 characters" -- when text string is only 4000 characters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working in a Google Sheets environment and when I use a formula with `SUBSTITUTE` in it - against a text string in a single cell that is 3,560 characters long - it works perfectly.

However, when the string grows to 4,047 characters long, I get a `#VALUE` error.

And when I hover over the cell with that #VALUE error, Google Sheets gives me an Error message that consists of:

> "Text result of SUBSTITUTE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters."

Now, I've measured the string length using a variety of tools and I am quite certain this functionality is breaking at only 4,047 characters.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, and how to overcome it?

For the record, I can provide the exact formula and the exact text string if required.

Comment: Please provide the sample. That would help to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: is the replacing string the same length as the one it is replacing? If it were much longer, it is possible the original string would be 4047 characters and the result would be too long. Or did you measure the result, anyway? As the others noted, your providing the sample would help, because otherwise it is guesswork (and I know this guess may be a bad one)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  The project, and the problem, have gone away.  I appreciate your willingness to help.  Regards